# Calculo de operaciones en jquery cuando cargue la pagina

Tags: php, jquery

Hola he intentado utilizar una función cuando cargo la página pero no me lo realiza correctamente no entiendo porque. Mi idea es que al cargar la página realice las operaciones al momento.

Adjunto mi código:

**PHP**

```
$id_operari=$row['tre_operario'];
echo "<td><input type='number' onchange='tt_percibe_inn($id_operari);' id='total_retri_nominas_$id_operari' name='total_retri_nominas_$id_operari' value='0' />€</td>";
```

**JQUERY**

```
function porcentaje(id){
  var irpf = $('#irpf_nominas_'+id).val();
  var ttal_retri = $('#total_retri_nominas_'+id).val();
  var porciento = 0;
  porciento += (ttal_retri*irpf/100);
  $('#total_irpf_nominas_'+id).val(porciento);
}
```

**JQUERY**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  porcentaje(id);
});
```

Comment: ¿Y el html?  No se ve lo que es `id` cuando llamas a la función `porcentaje(id)` dentro del `ready` me refiero.  Quizas debas sustituir ese `id` por un número correspondiente a esa página o algo, por lo tanto deberias sustituirlo con PHP antes de cargar el html supongo... ¿entiendes a lo que me refiero? ¿van por ahi los tiros?

Comment: Modificado @masterguru, mi idea es que segun la id del usuario haga un calculo u otro porque si eres el usuario 1 alomejor tus numeros son diferentes al 2.

Comment: Ya, pero tienes varios problemas diria yo. Primero que no se si tu formula funciona, porque no usas parseInt o parseFloat para los cálculos, y cuando recuperas datos con javascript siempre son en modo texto, aunque sean numeros, y debes parsearlos con alguna de esas funciones (no se si hay mas, creo que no).  Luego, tal como lo has puesto no hace nada porque id no equivale a nada durante la carga del documento (en el ready). Supongo que la solución pasa por identificar los inputs o columnas donde quieres  insertar ese calculo y mediante un bucle aplicar esa función a cada uno de ellos

Comment: Como debo identificar a los inputs y columnas y hacer el bucle?

Comment: Sólo con javascript podrias intentarlo mediante el uso de una clase en esos inputs, te la inventas, y se la aplicas a todos, y luego, mediante el uso de la función `.each` de jquery los recorres a todos, extrayendo sus id y lanzando tu funcion a cada uno de ellos, todo eso dentro del ready

Comment: okei entiendo gracias masterguru

Comment: Voy a redactarte una posible respuesta, pero la hago un poco a ciegas, pues no se el html de tus id #total_irpf_nominas_ que son los clave para hacer eso que he contado

Answer (score 1):

Una posible solución seria aplicar una clase única a ese campo donde quieres aplicar la fórmula, por ejemplo, `.total_irpf_nominas` y además aplicar un nuevo atributo a ellas, por ejemplo, `data-id=` que contenga el id a calcular.

Esto sería así en tu PHP que lo genera:

```php
<input class="total_irpf_nominas" data-id="<?php echo $id; ?>" id="total_irpf_nominas_<?php echo $id; ?>" readonly>
```

Y luego, en el javascript sería así:

```javascript
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.total_irpf_nominas').each(function( index ) {
     porcentaje($( this ).attr( "data-id" ));
  });
});
```

Seguramente quedará alguna cosa por pulir. Prueba y me comentas

Aquí te dejo un snippet funcional para que veas como funciona.

```js
function porcentaje(id){
  var irpf = $('#irpf_nominas_'+id).val();
  var ttal_retri = $('#total_retri_nominas_'+id).val();
  var porciento = 0;
  porciento += (ttal_retri*irpf/100);
  $('#total_irpf_nominas_'+id).val(porciento);
}

$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.total_irpf_nominas').each(function( index ) {
     porcentaje($( this ).attr( "data-id" ));
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr>
    <th>irpf_nominas</th>
    <th>total_retri_nominas</th>
    <th>total_irpf_nominas</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <input type="text" id="irpf_nominas_1" value="12" readonly>
    </td>
    <td>
      <input type="text" id="total_retri_nominas_1" value="112" readonly>
    </td>
    <td><input type="text" id="total_irpf_nominas_1" value="" class="total_irpf_nominas" data-id="1" readonly>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><input type="text" id="irpf_nominas_2" value="212" readonly></td>
    <td><input type="text" id="total_retri_nominas_2" value="11212" readonly></td>
    <td><input type="text" id="total_irpf_nominas_2" value="" class="total_irpf_nominas" data-id="2" readonly></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```